# What is dispatch(..).unwrap() in redux-toolkit?

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-toolkit

From a redux tutorial:

> ```
> const onSavePostClicked = async () => {
>   if (canSave) {
>     try {
>       setAddRequestStatus('pending')
>       await dispatch(addNewPost({ title, content, user: userId }))
>         .unwrap()
>     } catch (err) {
>       console.error('Failed to save the post: ', err)
>     } finally {
>       setAddRequestStatus('idle')
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

As I understand `dispatch(addNewPost({ title, content, user: userId }))` will return a promise like that:

```
state: "fulfilled"

result: fulfilled action object
```

and `dispatch(addNewPost({ title, content, user: userId })).unwrap()` will also return a promise.

So what is the difference between the promise without and with `unwrap`?

```
state: "fulfilled"

result: ?
```

Comment: It is specific to redux's `createAsyncThunk` method. `.unwrap()` isn't a native API on Promise's prototype, redux [adds this to the promise themselves](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/blob/a7ceaa209e0/packages/toolkit/src/createAsyncThunk.ts#L690-L692). See https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#unwrapping-result-actions

Comment: More details about this code are explained here: https://youtu.be/93CR_yURoII?t=1647

Answer (score 6):

`dispatch(addNewPost({ title, content, user: userId }))` will resolve to the latest action that has been dispatched by that thunk.

With `.unwrap()`, it will resolve to the value of the `fulfilled` action, or throw on a `rejected` action.

The idea here is that you should be able to `dispatch` an asyncThunk without having to catch it every time, but only if you really want to write more logic based on it.

Comment: but "catching" in javascript is just about `console.log(err)` usually. And so at that point I see no reason to logging or not catching at all since you would see the error anyway (if one was thrown)

Comment: @milanHrabos catching is almost never about logging, `console.log` is just something you see in examples and code that copy-pasted these examples without thinking.

Comment: I mean if you are in catch block it means you have an error and oftentimes there is nothing you can do but to just log it so that you know what that error is. Unless you 1) know the error beforehand and 2) have resolution for it (in context of frontend that could be updating UI with error message), there is not much you can do.

Answer (score 3):

In your e.g,

If `addNewPost` **succeeds**:

- It will pass through `unwrap()` without any issues

If `addNewPost` **fails** (rejected):

- `unwrap()` will throw the rejected value

The thrown value/error will be caught in the catch block & your error message will be logged

If you were to log `dispatch(addNewPost({ title, content, user: userId })).unwrap()`, it would like this if there `addNewPost` succeeds:

[image]

**Note: this is without the `await` keyword for your `dispatch`**

*Read more:* https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/error-handling#error-display-examples

Answer (score 1):

You can get the [official document](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-5-async-logic#checking-thunk-results-in-components) about the `.unwrap` usage case.

> createAsyncThunk handles any errors internally, so that we don't see any messages about "rejected Promises" in our logs. It then returns the final action it dispatched: either the fulfilled action if it succeeded, or the rejected action if it failed.

> However, it's common to want to write logic that looks at the success or failure of the actual request that was made. Redux Toolkit adds a .unwrap() function to the returned Promise, which will return a new Promise that either has the actual action.payload value from a fulfilled action, or throws an error if it's the rejected action. This lets us handle success and failure in the component using normal try/catch logic.

[image]

**In one world, It help you can `catch` the error which has been wraped by `createAsyncThunk` in your components**

Hope it can helps you

Answer (score 0):

From the `reduxjs/toolkit` docs

> "However, it's common to want to write logic that looks at the success
> or failure of the actual request that was made. Redux Toolkit adds a
> .unwrap() function to the returned Promise, which will return a new
> Promise that either has the actual action.payload value from a
> fulfilled action, or throws an error if it's the rejected action"

[Source](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-5-async-logic#checking-thunk-results-in-components)

Answer (score -1):

If you need to access the error or success payload immediately after a mutation, you can chain .unwrap().

```
addPost({ id: 1, name: 'Example' })
.unwrap()
.then((payload) => console.log('fulfilled', payload))
.catch((error) => console.error('rejected', error))
```

As you can see, the .unwrap() method exposes the error and payload which you can use.

see ---> https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/error-handling

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).